# if uniform cost search is optimal why we need depth A* search

Tags: artificial-intelligence

if uniform cost search is optimal why we need depth A* search?
I read that uniform cost search is optimal and A* search is also optimal. If its the case then why do we even consider A* search

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"optimal" only means that both algorithms are guaranteed to eventually find a correct and optimal solution if one exists. Typically, A* will be significantly more efficient from a computational point of view (takes less processing time before finding a solution)